# Why does this bash script give an error on Ubuntu but not OSX

Tags: ubuntu, bash, cron, crontab, node.js

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
export $NODE_CONFIG_DIR=/Users/full/path/to/script/config
cd /Users/full/path/to/script
/usr/local/bin/node main
```

The script runs locally on OSX (if I adjust the paths for the local environment) but on Ubuntu I get:

```
./mtf_runner.sh: 2: export: : bad variable name
```

I want to run the script using cron and need to set the `NODE_CONFIG_DIR` environment variable

Additionally, although the command runs in `cron` on OSX (10.8.5), I do get the following sent to my local mail:

```
line 2: export: `=/Users/myname/Node/Development/tennistracker/config': not a valid identifier
```

I've read that this could be caused by a space around `=` but there is definitely no space

Comment: A script that specifies `#!/usr/bin/env sh` as its script interpreter is **not a bash script**, [not on Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh), [not on Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/DashAsBinSh), and [not on NetBSD](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?sh++NetBSD-current).

Answer (score 4):

This is caused by the fact that when setting a variable, you should not prefix it with $. Here, the $NODE_CONFIG_DIR is expanded into nothing (as it is unset) before running the line, which makes you run `export =/Users/full/path/to/script/config`. The script should be

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
export NODE_CONFIG_DIR=/Users/full/path/to/script/config
cd /Users/full/path/to/script
/usr/local/bin/node main
```

Answer (score 0):

While the usage of avoiding "$" as a variable prefix is correct, there is another difference.  On OSX systems, 'sh' is 'bash'.  That is, it is a Bourne-type shell.  This can be verified on Mac by simply doing a

```
man sh
```

On Ubuntu, 'sh' is 'dash'.  Dash is a Korn-type shell.  You can also see this via the 'man' page or by doing:

```
ls -al /bin/sh
```

So if you want to ensure that your scripts act the same on both systems, do a:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

instead of the normal 'sh'.